# Install: GitHub gamejs

Tags: github, installation

I started today working with gamejs for a small project. I saw that most project are repository files on github dot com, so I downloaded the github for windows and the git bash.

Then I used git bash to clone gamejs repository. I proceed the same with some repository stuff. However, it seems that I forget to install something... because I cannot start the server, I have gjs-server.sh or .cmd missing. The bash doesnt recognize the command. What will I do?

Comment: "because I cannot start the server, I have gjs-server.sh or .cmd missing" this sounds like a very old version of gamejs. did you try one of the release zips? those are easiest to get started with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cloned the code instead of downloading the release tarball you need to [build](http://gamejs.org/installation/) GameJS first:

> Change into the GameJs directory
>
> ```
> cd gamejs
> ```
>
> Get all needed submodules with git:
>
> ```
> git submodule init git submodule update
> ```
>
> Compile RingoJs:
>
> ```
> ant -f ./server/ringojs/build.xml jar
> ```

**EDIT:** Prior to building you need to install [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build tool. Since it is a Java application to install it just download the binary distribution from their [download page](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) and unzip it.

Comment: TY very much for reply. Finally we're getting somewhere. I already build gamejs (like in the installation notes), but I didn't compile ringoJS. The issue is: I don't have 'ant' and I don't know how to get it. I did a search on github but the 'ant' I've found was for linux only. Where do I get this 'ant'?